# Голосіїв чи Голосієво, Пирогів чи Пирогово?

Tags: росіянізм, власні-назви

Інтуїтивно відчуваю, що по-українськи **Голосіїв** і **Пирогів** (за аналогією з `Київ`, `Миколаїв`, `Зміїв`, `Іркліїв` тощо), а не **`Голосієво`** й **`Пирогово`** , але на підтвердження знайшла лиш одну нотатку на сайті ["Мова- ДНК нації"](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/u-golosievo,-u-golosievomu-chu-v-golosievi).

Опосередкований аргумент того, що варіанти *`Голосієво`*, *`Пирогово`* вживаються внаслідок багаторічного радянського зросійщення, бачу в [Українському правописі (2015)](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm):

> § 109. Географічні назви слов’янських та інших країн <...>
>
> Географічні назви з прикметниковими закінченнями <...>
>
> б) Російські назви з кінцевими `-ово`, -`єво` та `-ино` передаються
>   через `-ово`, `-єво` та `-іно (-їно)`, після шиплячих — `-ино`:
>   `Внуково`, `Орєхово-Зуєво`; `Бородіно`, `Мар’їно`, `Пушкіно`;
>   `Єгоршино`, `Рощино`.

Наразі в загальному вжитку плутанина, бо існують паралельно обидві форми.

**Голосіїв**

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D1%97%D0%B2)

[Голосіївська РДА](http://golos.kievcity.gov.ua/content/mennyu-1.html)

[Цікавий Київ](http://pamyatky.kiev.ua/articles/mesta/golosiyiv)

**Голосієво**

[Голосіївська РДА1](http://golos.kievcity.gov.ua/content/turystam.html)

[Національний університет біоресурсів і природокористування України](https://nubip.edu.ua/node/23909)

**Пирогів**

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B2_(%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2))

[Національний музей народної архітектури та побуту України](http://www.primetour.ua/uk/excursions/museum/Muzey-narodnoy-arhitekturyi-i-byita--Pirogovo-.html)

**Пирогово**

[Перше екскурсійне бюро](http://www.primetour.ua/uk/excursions/museum/Muzey-narodnoy-arhitekturyi-i-byita--Pirogovo-.html)

**Чи є наукове обгрунтування правильності якогось із варіантів** (**на** `**-ів**` **чи на** `**-ово/-єво**`)?

Comment: Чи не пов'язане це з типом населеного пункту (точніше, із загальною назвою типу населеного пункту, яка побутувала *в часи закріплення* власної назви конкретного населеного пункту): місто/село/селище/тощо — Голосієво, го́род/за́мок/присілок/тощо — Голосіїв, фортеця/«дєрєвня»/тощо — Голосієва? Звісно, може, й дурна гіпотеза — але спростування теж цікаво.

Comment: Не впевнена. Хоча ні підтверджень, ні спростувань такої гіпотези не зустрічала.

Comment: Є ще [такий коментар](http://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/133469.html?thread=1726557#t1726557) щодо назв *-ськ/-цьк* VS. *-ське/-цьке*: «*Поширення* -цьке (-ське) *в географічних назвах це данина експериментальним правописам 1920-х років. Справа в тому, що на міста, для яких характерний давніший суфікс* -цьк, -ськ, *намагалися штучно перенести формант середнього роду, характерний для сіл та селищ.*»

Answer (score 5):

> Голосіїв
>   <sub>– [Ортографічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53395/66248.html)
>
>   – [УЛІФ НАН України](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D1%97%D0%B2)</sub>
>
> Пирогів
>   <sub>– [Ортографічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53407/149462.html)
>
>   – [УЛІФ НАН України](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B2)</sub>

Натомість *Пирогово* й *Голосієво* в словниках відсутні.

Comment: Я думаю, Оксану Губренко більше цікавило якесь загальне правило/загальна теорія з приводу цих назв. Але дякую за конкретну відповідь — комусь (хто зайде в це запитання, шукаючи правопис конкретних назв) воно явно допоможе.

Comment: @Sasha, дякую за точний коментар. Автору відповіді, Follower, вітм, теж спасибі!